# Webpage to to run programs

Tags: php, windows, taskkill

Hi all I'm brand new to PHP so go easy here. :)

I am attempting to make a bare minimum webpage to run various things on my computer.

For example, I have a button and am attempting to run the following:

```
<?php
exec("taskkill /IM iexplore.exe");
?>
```

However, nothing happens. I've read a bunch on Google and here, but I can't find anything that explains this problem. I am on Win 7, UAC disabled, running the latest version of WAMP. (Everything I've found so far addresses IIS)

Could some one point me in the right direction?

Comment: Where is your PHP code?  That exec will run on the PHP server, not on the client (unless they happen to be one and the same...)

Comment: I would argue that PHP is not the technology to use if you want to run/kill applications on your computer. I would look into Perl, Java or VB.NET. Perl is likely the easiest to learn.

Comment: No, I want PHP. I'm creating a small webpage to kill running programs on my server from my iPhone.

Comment: Looks like some switches might be missing.  For reference, here's the manpage: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009.aspx

Comment: Just a tip: On shared hosting you may not be able to run a shell command since they are most probably configured to be blocked for security reasons. If you are running on your own server, then things can change.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)

You can also use this built in function from the [PHP Manual](http://pt.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php#90664) :

Hope this helps

```
function runAsynchronously($path,$arguments) {
    $WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");  
    $oShellLink = $WshShell->CreateShortcut("temp.lnk");  
    $oShellLink->TargetPath = $path;  
    $oShellLink->Arguments = $arguments;  
    $oShellLink->WorkingDirectory = dirname($path);  
    $oShellLink->WindowStyle = 1;  
    $oShellLink->Save();  
    $oExec = $WshShell->Run("temp.lnk", 7, false);  
    unset($WshShell,$oShellLink,$oExec);  
    unlink("temp.lnk");  
}
```

Answer (score -2):

exec() is for CLI mode (locally). Play with your bash.

Comment: If the PHP file is executing on a web server you cannot cause a web browser to open a new process like that!

Comment: There might be some confusion in interpreting what you meant.  Because 'windows' tag was used, it can be assumed 'bash' is not relevant here.  Also, `exec` PHP function is not reserved for CLI environment only.

Comment: `Because 'windows' tag was used, it can be assumed 'bash' is not relevant here` Why? There are bash for Windows too, not only in *nix. Before you vote down someone answer, at least do some little research. I think it was huge security breach, if for whatsoever reason, you can trigerring Windows computer to pop up or run a program/task by added something in your php application. PHP is a server side languange, and impossible to doing that unless, like i stated, you do that in your local computer and executed your php code from CLI (most of all use bash).